# Can not open() a text file with file position as a variable

Tags: python, pyqt

When I try to open a file with path assigned to the 'path', it just end the code without any error. But if I just copy and paste the path ('C:/Users/ahmet/OneDrive/Masaüstü/G-code Fix/bum.txt') into the open() it open and does the for loop without any problem

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtWidgets,QtCore
import sys
import os


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self , files, oldcode,path ,path2):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sürükle Bırak")
        self.resize(720, 480)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.files = files
        self.init_ui()
        self.oldcode = oldcode
        self.path = path
        self.path2 = path2

    def init_ui(self):

        pass


    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        files = [u.toLocalFile() for u in event.mimeData().urls()]
        print(str(files).replace('[','').replace(']',''))
        path = str(files).replace('[','').replace(']','')
        print(path)
        oldcode = open(path , 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        b = oldcode.readlines()
        c = [x.replace('\n','')for x in b]
        print(c)
        print(len(c))
        for i in range(0,len(c)):

            if c[i] == 'xd':
                c[i]='lolz'


        oldcode.close


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = MainWidget(files=0,oldcode='',path2='',path='')
ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

these are the output

```
'C:/Users/ahmet/OneDrive/Masaüstü/G-code Fix/bum.txt'
'C:/Users/ahmet/OneDrive/Masaüstü/G-code Fix/bum.txt'

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: You should research how to get an item from a list.

Comment: ok this was pretty easy Idk why I tried to convert into a string first. Thank you but I dont still get it why this one does not work

Comment: you can try adding a print(oldcode) under `oldcode = ...`  to see if the error happening with opening the file or not.  If it is then it is likely the filepath that is wrong.